# How to add a custom UI Controller as the targettype in WPF ResouceDictionary File

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Style x:Key=CustomDataGrid" TargetType="{x:Type CusGrid}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Red.Background}" />
   </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have created a custom data grid with additional functionalities and I am planning to style it using this resource dictionary file. But it gives an error when I type `TargetType="{x:Type CusGrid}"`. How may I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a **namespace prefix** to your root element in the XAML.

Your question doesn't indicate what C# namespace your custom control is located in, so I'll just use `XYZ` as a placeholder. Add a new attribute to your `ResourceDictionary` element like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary ... xmlns:mycontrols="clr-namespace:XYZ">
```

replacing `XYZ` with the actual namespace that your `CusGrid` control is located in.

Next, change your `TargetType` to this:

```
... TargetType="{x:Type mycontrols:CusGrid}">
```

See how the *mycontrols* namespace prefix is used in front of the `CusGrid` type name.

You can change *mycontrols* to be anything you want, as long as you don't use a prefix that's already referenced (so you couldn't use *x* as a prefix for example).